# Error opening default.aspx in SharePoint Designer 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer, publishing-site

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I am using SharePoint Designer 2007 to open `default.aspx` under Pages sub-folder (selecting edit page layout in SharePoint designer 2007) of a site, but `welcomesplash.aspx` displays other than `default.aspx` itself, why?

Answer (score 4):

Well, it sounds like you are using the publishing features of MOSS.  With the publishing features you have a page layout that is applied to a page.  You will not be able to edit this page directly except through the UI by adding webparts or changing values in the field controls.  When you try to edit a page that is using a page layout in SP Designer, it will ask you if you just want to edit the page layout.  This is by design.

Comment: Steve is right.  You can move around the web parts and edit the content through the browser, but you cannot edit the "page" in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Do you mean "welcomesplash.aspx" is the page layout of default.aspx? If yes, how do we know (e.g. from code or config) that "welcomesplash.aspx" is the page layout of default.aspx (i.e. I want to learn for an aspx page, how to know which is its layout page)?

Comment: Hi next_connect, do you mean "welcomesplash.aspx" is the page layout of default.aspx? If yes, how do we know (e.g. from code or config) that "welcomesplash.aspx" is the page layout of default.aspx (i.e. I want to learn for an aspx page, how to know which is its layout page)?

Comment: From the page editing toolbar, you can click on the page menu and select page settings.  This will show you the current page layout that the page is connected to and allow you to change it to a different page layout of the same content type.  This will display the title of the page layout.  You can then go to the masterpages and page layouts gallery to match that name with the file name of the page layout.  You might need to edit the view and add the title column to make the match.  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Also be aware that editing master pages, page layouts and pages in SharePoint designer will customize (old jargon: unghost) that page.

Doing this on a publishing site will cause you a world of pain in upgrade and/or rebranding scenarios.

Changes to for example page layouts should be done in the feature that deploys that page.

Comment: "a world of pain in upgrade and/or rebranding scenarios" -- for example?

Comment: "example page layouts" -- what do you mean example page layouts?

Comment: 1) when for example a page layout or a master is unghosted, it is stored in the database not on the file system (in the feature that defined it). This means that when you for example want to rebrand the solution, the HTML isnt changed along with all the other pages that uses the ghosted master page / page layout, so you will have two layouts for the site and will have to dig out all unghosted pages and reghost them, while trying to remember if there was anything important functionality on that page that will now be lost since you reghost it...

2) i wrote "for example page layouts"